# How can I generate a temporary file name on another machine?

Tags: c#

I need to write my data to a file on another machine. Previously, everything was on one machine, so I used

```
var fileTmp = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileTmp, data);
```

But how can I generate a temporary file name on another machine, e.g. MyServerName?

Thanks

Comment: You first need to connect to that machine

Comment: Could you please give me more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have local admin access to the other machine you can use the admin share

```
\\HOSTNAME\c$\pathtofile
```

You can generate a unique file name like this

```
var myUniqueFileName = string.Format(@"{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: +1 for the shares idea, but I would consider using a restricted folder, rather than sharing C drive, especially if it has OS files on it. You would also need to send Admin credentials to get access to that  drive, which may not be secure.

Comment: But the actual problem is how to generate "pathtofile". System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() gives me a path on the local machine.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to generate a unique file name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing so. Otherwise your computer would be full with viruses.

You will have to use some sort of networking service and expose that service from a remote machine. I would consider:

- ASP NET RESTful API
- WCF service
- Windows service with message queue provider
- Network shares

Be careful with security though. Write permissions must not be easily granted to a network service.